# Basic PHP MySQL Form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

*Fixed code below posted for reference (second section of code works first did not)

**old post** 
Not working and I have worked on it all weekend. I get data in my database by its not the value from the form.

I am getting the following error,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'INTO' (T_STRING) in /Users/hunterjamesnelson/Sites/290Website/Back end/p5services-backend/test.php on line 51

This is referring to this line...

```
 $sql=INSERT INTO user(first-name,last-name,email) VALUES(isset($_POST['firstname']), isset($_POST['lasttname']), isset($_POST['email']));}
```

I suspect the issues are related to how I used quotes, but as of not it seems I have tried every logical placement and now am left with this.

Here is all of the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>test</h1>
<form action="test.php" method="post">

    FirstName:<input type="text" name"firstname"> <br>
    LastName:<input type="text" name"lasttname"> <br>
    Email:<input type="text" name"email"> <br>
    <!-- UserName:<input type="text" name"username"> <br>
    Phone:<input type="text" name"phone"> <br> -->

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "p5services";

// Create connection
$dbc = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$dbc) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// form VALUES
// $Fname = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
// $Lname = isset($_POST['lasttname']) ? $_POST['lasttname'] : '';
// $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$sql=INSERT INTO user(first-name,last-name,email) VALUES(isset($_POST['firstname']), isset($_POST['lasttname']), isset($_POST['email']));}

if (mysqli_query($dbc, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($dbc);
}

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

**end old post**

*Here is what I ended up using that works, maybe it will help some one out...

UserName:    
    Password:

```
<!-- start signup submit -->
<?php 
include '_include/php/mysqli_connect.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit_login'])) {
//set up session if the form was posted
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {
        $un = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        if(isset($un, $pass)) {
            $q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name='$un' AND pass='$pass' LIMIT 1";

            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
                $_SESSION["loggedin"] = 1;
                $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row['user_id'];
                $_SESSION["username"] = $row['user_name'];
                $_SESSION["first_name"] = $row['first_name'];
                $_SESSION["roll"] = $row['roll_id'];
                $loggedin = 1;
                $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
                $username = $_SESSION['username'];
                echo "Valid entery!";

            } else {
                $loginerror = "Invalid Username/Password Combination";
                echo $loginerror;
            }
        } else {
            session_destroy();
            $loginerror = "Username/Password field was empty";
            echo "else2";
        }
    }
} //end if submit_login
 ?>
<!-- end signup submit -->
```

Comment: try adding '' arround the query, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp will help you i guess

Comment: Try enabling error reporting first. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very top of your file after `<?php`. This would tell you about all the errors that may exist on your page.

Comment: Like @SvenB said, use quotes.  Also, parameterize your queries. Using values straight off the $_POST is very dangerous. Here's the PHP doc with an example: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @SvenB Opinion: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use.

Comment: @JohnConde: yes, w3schools sucks, but MDN doesn't teach PHP.

Comment: `isset($_POST['firstname'])` This returns a boolean, which is useless inside a string

Comment: @Wooble Forgot to remove that part of the comment. It's copy and paste. :/

Comment: does any one see any reason that my, "if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {" would not be working? My code is submitting null content before I enter form data and telling me my values in $_POST are undefined right off the bat...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Sven B pointed out, you're missing quotes. But there's more going on here that should be worked on.

Development Environments should always have error reporting enabled. The simplest is to do:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Next, as you're accepting user input, this makes you vulnerable to `SQL Injection`. To address that, we'll use prepared statements. Also, we'll check if the values are set initially, so we don't have to worry about people inserting multiple rows in the database with null values (in the event that your columns accept nulls)

```
if(isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['email'])):
    $dbc = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
    $dbc->prepare("insert into user(`first-name`,`last-name`,email) VALUES(?,?,?)");
    $dbc->bind_param('sss', $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['email']);
    $dbc->execute();
endif;
```

This will keep you vulnerable from SQL injection, and will also ensure you don't get a bunch of nulled out rows inserted into your database.

You'll also notice the backticks surrounding your column names that contain hyphens. This is necessary given your column names.

1. [MySQLI prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
2. [MySQLI bind param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score 0):

You got 2 errrors, first, you must add quotes to the query. Second, you shouldn't use isset() when you're sending it to the database, because isset just returns TRUE and FALSE (booleans) if variables exist. Try with:

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    // protect against SQL injection 
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape($dbc, $_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape($dbc, $_POST['lastname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape($dbc, $_POST['email']);

     $sql= "INSERT INTO user(first-name,last-name,email) VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email')");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your query in " " and you have a

like this:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO user(first-name,last-name,email) VALUES($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lasttname'],$_POST['email'])";
```

Also, I would really recommend using a prepared statement like this:

```
$sql = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO user(first-name,last-name,email) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$sql->bind_param('sss', $_POST['firstname'],$_POST['lastname'],$_POST['email']);
$sql->execute();
```

Comment: Just implementing use of "" in my query I get the following error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: I have got this before as well, it is referring to, $sql= "INSERT INTO user(first-name,last-name,email) VALUES($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lasttname'],$_POST['email'])";}

Comment: Either way, go with the prepared statement (second code block). The first one is very unsafe!

Comment: I plan on it, I wanted to get it working in the most simplistic way first, but am working with the second code block right now. Thanks!